# Is it possible to make a process alive during reboot?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I want to make a process alive during reboot. I am thinking that, I can backup all process related information and i will store it on some file. After reboot i will take that data back and by using that i will create a process again. Is my thinking is correct? Please clarify.

Comment: Google "persistence" or "persisting state".

Comment: See also [Application Checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) and [Continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) wikipages

Comment: See also [Checkpoint/Restore](http://criu.org/), which is part of the latest kernels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too vague.  Can you provide with more information?  I can give a basic outline of what is required to run a process on system startup.

**Deamonize**
A process must be a deamon (it shouldn't run in the context of a terminal) Read deamon process for more information.

**chkconfig**
Use this to add your deamon to your system startup run levels. `sudo chkconfig deamon_name on`